# Trigger Async Validation Only on blur but the Sync Validation should be triggered always

Tags: angular, typescript

```
email:new FormControl(null,{validators:[Validators.required,this.isRestrictedEmail],asyncValidators:[this.isEmailPresent],updateOn:'blur'})
```

Sync Validation should be triggered always but the async validation should be triggered only on blur event

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.